# How do I get an html/css form to post to Gravity Forms?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a 'Photoshop (.psd) to WordPress' landing page conversion project that I began by converting to a basic html/css page including a nonfunctional, but correctly styled form.

The project scope expanded with the need to post user entries to the Gravity Forms plugin in WordPress.

How do I need to modify my existing html/css form (since I've already created the styles) and submit the entries to the Gravity Forms form in the WordPress dashboard?

I'd like to do this without starting from scratch on the html and form styles.

**HTML/CSS Version**: http://dev.sweatergod.com/safeguard/

**WordPress Template Version**: http://dev.ira123.com/self-directed-ira-llc-landing-page/

Neither one have the Gravity Forms form integrated yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Gravity forms API, the easiest way, if you don't want to sacrifice your current styles, would be to have your current form POST to the gravity forms API.

http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Web_API#POST_.2Fentries

POST /forms/[Form ID]/entries
URI: /gravityformsapi/forms/[Form ID]/entries

Description: Creates/adds entries for the specified Form ID

Input: A JSON string containing a collection of entries that will be added

Output: A localized message describing the result: "Entries created successfully"