# How can I successfully use a WordPress plugin to add styling to a website?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Some people are already styling their own websites, so is it possible
[How do I get an html/css form to post to Gravity Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944725/how-do-i-get-an-html-css-form-to-post-to-gravity-forms)

Here is the link that also recognizes the problems that wordpress has, with users adding code, but it says if you download this plugin, your problems will be solved: [Raw HTML plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/raw-html/).

Here are the instructions from the website above:

> To install the plugin follow these steps :
>
> 1. Download the raw-html.zip file to your local machine.
> 2. Go to ‘Plugins -> Add New -> Upload’.
> 3. Upload the zip file using the provided form.
> 4. Activate the plugin through the ‘Plugins’ menu in WordPress
>
> Alternatively, you can search for “Raw HTML” in ‘Plugins -> Add New -> Search’ and install it from there, or unzip raw-html.zip and
>   upload the raw-html directory to your /wp-content/plugins directory.

I generally get to the point where I download the plugin (step 1, raw form) and then I am unable to proceed further. What should software I open the plugin with or do I need to go online (and where) to download the correct software?

Comment: I assume step 2 refers to some kind of admin panel within WordPress, although I can't say I've used it. See e.g. https://en.support.wordpress.com/plugins/adding-plugins

Comment: This is saying contradictory information, maybe I don't need a plugin?http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-introduction/adding-html-wordpress

Comment: I don't know - again, I haven't used WP. Your question seems to be about installing a plugin, hence the above support link.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Add custom HTML? Add custom CSS? Globally or based on post-types?

Comment: I want to achieve being able to use checkboxes, buttons, and text to go to differnet dungeons and dragons situations: the text would say where do you want to go? with the multiple choice to choose one checkbox of the folllowing options: a camp in the hills, a town, a forest, or a castle on the plains...this would in turn lead to a video of a forest....or a mountain...or a cave by the sea...  It is possible that WordPress may not be the best option for this....

Comment: @janh: I want to add html,css, bootstrap, and jquery. But the problem is getting the right form

Answer (score 1):

Basically, I found out that certain software is required, not the plugin, to allow styling to the website. The link to access this feature is: [how-to-use-plugin-not](https://www.taniarascia.com/local-environment/) and she explains step by step. This thing type is for people using CSS, Bootstrap, HTML5, and JQuery. As far as I can see, no amount of research shows that a plugin is necessary but I was correct that certain preparatory steps were necessary. This is different than and unique from other methods of deeper coding.

Going to GitHub for an online portfolio would be more appropriate (shows your mastery more). This is according to Joshua Scott from free code camp but WordPress is great to develop CMS skills according to Jamie Schmidt, a developer for eight years.

Answer (score -1):

The quick and dirty way that doesn't need any plugins or fiddling with the theme: throw your code into the content of the page you want it to appear on. Adding  in the body is perfectly fine, and linking stylesheets outside of head works, even though it's not allowed in the specifications.

To do it the right way, you'll have to get your hands dirty and use a custom template file for the HTML and add your scripts and styles via wp_enqueue_script/wp_enqueue_style.

Comment: Ive tried to do that. I've literally copied and pasted a correct copy made by and the link is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513022/how-do-i-add-html-css-bootstrap-or-jquery-to-a-wordpress-site-to-change-the-b?noredirect=1#comment80021127_46513022   question..,the answer as it stands helps the community already. But I still get just text in the text editor when adding those pieces of code as suggested.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Have you changed the editor from visual to text? Otherwise inserting HTML would lead to it being escaped and you'd end up seeing the markup instead of having it interpreted.

Comment: I've added some html features (like changing regular paragraph text to heading text by changing the code, not by using the buttons). Again, I changed the text to heading format using coding....I'm currently trying to find why I cant add a style section -i.e., it appears as regular paragraph text when I go to text editor and add a style section.